# Rav Yosef Caro's lack of Sefer HaMitzvos

Tags: sources-mekorot, rambam

A friend of mine once claimed that Rav Yosef Caro didn't have access to Rambam's Sefer HaMitzvos. It's apparently evident from comments he makes in Beis Yosef and Kessef Mishnah. I was hoping to see some examples where this is evident.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps he meant to share the claim regarding a number of Rishonim.

From [Halachipedia](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Rambam#Sefer_HaMitzvot)

> There's a debate regarding if specific Rishonim such as the Samag,
>   Maggid Mishneh, and Migdal Oz saw the Sefer HaMitzvot, as it wasn't
>   translated from Arabic to Hebrew for some time. Later Acharonim culled
>   lists of instances in which each of them cites the Sefer HaMitzvot to
>   dispel those claims.[38]

Regarding your friend's, claim, I wonder how tenable it is given R' Yosef Karo had all these Rishonim.

Also, a quick search on Bar Ilan for "*ספר המצו*ת" in Kesef Mishneh, Beit Yosef, and Avkat Rochel yield over a hundred results. True, some are for the ספר מצות גדול\קטן, there are a bunch that clearly are citing the Rambam in the sefer and in the shorashim.

Comment: Didn't Rav Yosef Caro know Arabic? Also, wasn't Sefer HaMitzvos translated by ibn Tibbon in Rambam's lifetime?

Comment: Those are also good reasons to say this claim is incorrect.

Comment: Indeed, SH was translated durring the Rabmams lifetime. In his responsa he even directs non arabic speakers to it

Comment: @Mbrevda I think he even referred them to it before it was translated, on the grounds that so much of it is quotations from the Gemara that even someone who doesn't understand Arabic would be able to get the general gist.